# swi Prolog tracing recursion depth

Tags: prolog, trace, factorial

Why does the recursion depth start with 6 or 7 when tracing Prolog programs?

Example (taken form [here](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/tracing.html)).

```
factorial(0, 1).
factorial(N, NFact) :-
    N > 0,
    Nminus1 is N - 1,
    factorial(Nminus1, Nminus1Fact),
    NFact is Nminus1Fact * N.
```

Lets trace `factorial(3, X)`. The output is:

```
Call: (7) factorial(3, _G284) ? creep*
Call: (8) 3>0 ? creep
Exit: (8) 3>0 ? creep
Call: (8) _L205 is 3-1 ? creep
```

and so on. The first column (`Call, Exist`) are the ports, the third are the goals and the second is the recursion depth. But why does it start with 7? (When I run the example on my machine it starts with 6) Shouldn't it rather start with 1 or 0?